# How to efficiently find if a string contains a dictionary word?

Tags: regex, unix

I have one list of URLs, and one dictionary.

What is the most efficient way to find which URLs contain at least one word that is in the dictionary ? The dictionary contains 100.000 words, and I have 700.000 URLs to test.

You can assume that the dictionary is /usr/share/dict/american-english for example.

I assume that regular expressions engines compile an expression like this `word1|word2|..|wordn` into an efficient finite automata which runs in linear time once compiled.

Basically I'm looking for the most direct way to build this regexp `"word_1|..|word_n"` where n=100.000

Answer (score 1):

You can just try with `grep`. Example data:

```
$  cat urls.txt 
http://www.foo.com
http://www.google.com
http://www.bar.com
http://www.stackoverflow.com

$  cat dictionary.txt 
foo
buz
bar
bez
stack
```

Grep in action:

```
grep -f dictionary.txt urls.txt
```

Output:

```
http://www.foo.com
http://www.bar.com
http://www.stackoverflow.com
```

Comment: GNU grep allows the search for matches that form whole words. Eg in the example above "stackoverflow" is considered to be a word and so is not matched with "stack". See "-w" in http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html

Comment: Just be careful with the formatting of the dictionary, particularly unix end of lines vs windows end of lines. Otherwise, it's working but I'm not sure about the performances. I'm doing a benchmark right now.

Comment: grep -f is not usable with large (100000s of words)  dictionaries

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how much faster this would be, but it might work ok.

I used a hash to store all the words and then search for every possible word.  Hashes are fast for searching so it might work better than grep. (probably not though - who knows what dark magic is inside of grep!)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

# Build a hash containing all the words.
open FILE, '/usr/share/dict/words';
my %dict;
foreach (<FILE>) {
  chomp;
  $dict{$_} = 1;
}

# Function to test if a string has words.
sub haswords {
   my $_ = shift;
   my @list = split '';
   for (my $i=0; $i<=$#list; $i++) {
      for (my $j=$i+1; $j<=$#list; $j++) {
         my $word = join('', @list[$i .. $j]);
         if (defined($dict{$word})) {
            return 1;
         }
      }
   }
}

# Test it.
foreach (<>) {
   chomp;
   if (haswords($_)) {
      print "$_ has words\n";
   } else {
      print "$_ no words\n";
   }
}
```

Output:

```
yeshaswords has words
kakalkdkak has words
vvvvvvvv no words
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the +1.  Did you try my version?  I'd love to know if it was faster.